# Can anyone explain the order of battle in pvp for Dungeon Boss?

Tags: dungeon-boss

It seems to be completely random, i.e. my team gets an initial attack, but then the defending team may get 1 or all attacks. It appears really imbalanced to me, not that I want to go in, cast taunt and laugh or anything, but, can I affect the order of which character I can use first? Or is there a set order/preference? Or even, is it Fast >> Slow etc? Thanks.

Comment: I made the tag for you. Feel free to add some information to it.

Answer (score 3):

A recent patch has made some changes for how heroes take turns during raids. All information here is the result of actual game play.

Heroes in general fall under one of three different speed categories: fast, normal, and slow. All fast heroes will go before the other heroes, one at a time. Then all normal heroes will take their turns, followed by the slow heroes. In all cases, a hero for the defensive player will go first if he/she has a hero in that speed category.

When selecting heroes to attack or defend, their selection order will set their turn order. As you select heroes for your raid/defense, they will be assigned a number. Heroes will be assigned a turn based on their speed category and the order they were selected in.

For example, consider the following selection of heroes and their speed categories:

Rogar Stonecrusher (normal), Tsume (normal), Stone Fist (slow), Willow Swift (fast)

Their turn order would be Willow, Rogar, Tsume, and Stone Fist. If you are defending, then Willow will **always** go first. If you are attacking, then Willow will go after any fast heroes on the defensive side, if any. If the defense does not have any fast heroes, then Willow will be the first hero to act.

If you decide that you want to change the order of the heroes you've selected for a particular speed category, keep in mind that the order you've selected them in is used to determine that order. So, if you want to swap Rogar's turn number with Tsume's, then you simply need to deselect Rogar, and then re-add him. When Rogar is deselected, Tsume will move from turn 3 to turn 2, and re-adding Rogar will place him in turn 3, since he's still faster than Stone First who is a slow hero. This behavior is the same for any heroes in a particular speed category.

And that's just about it. Determine what heroes you'd like to select while considering their speed categories, ensure you select all heroes of a particular speed category in the order that you want them to activate, and you can now manipulate when each hero will take their turn.

Comment: This is pretty spot on but just be aware the hero selection per speed category (fast, normal, slow) is round robin. Its not All of the fast defenders go then all of the fast attackers. Its the first fast defender, the first fast attacker and then it continues back and forth until all fast heroes are taken care of. It will then go to normal and do the same thing, then finally slow. After that it starts over again (though honestly most PvP is really done after the first round.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out in the end. It appears that Fast characters are > Slow. That being said, if the opponent has a full team of Fast characters, they will get first attack regardless. If for example you have a full team of Fast characters and your opponent has 1, they attack first with that one character and then you get to use all of yours in succession.

So, in conclusion :

Opponent Fast >> Your Fast characters.

Comment: Assuming the same speed attributes on both sides, the defending player always gets to go first. Fast defenders go before Fast attackers, non Fast/Slow defenders go before non Fast/Slow attackers, and Slow defenders go before Slow attackers.

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? I've actually experienced this exact same behavior.